# How to avoid div to be displayed on a new line

Tags: html, css

I have a list of div displayed on the same line. When the page is not wide enough to display all the div on the same line, I don't want extra div to be displayed on the next line. How can I avoid displaying extra div on a new line?

Here is a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YCFZM/

Try to reduce width on the page and you'll see some div displayed on a new line.

Thanks.

Comment: You have fixed number of divs?

Comment: Yuor jsFiddle code is invalid. Please fix it and post the new URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated gist with solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Meligy/YCFZM/16/

Main changes:

- Removed extra quote in HTML at `id=""sidebar"` which was breaking the gist
- Removed `height: 0px;` from `div#sidebar` CSS
- Added `white-space:nowrap;` to `div#sidebar` CSS
- Removed `float:left` from `div.sidebar-item` CSS
- Added `white-space: nowrap; display:inline-block;` to `div.sidebar-item` CSS

Optionally you can also remove `text-align:center;` from  `div#sidebar` CSS if you meant to make the text be to the left.

Answer (score 0):

In the style sheet use the display attribute with the inline value on the doc

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge goes the only solution to this is to have a fixed width for the container. Or to have an element in the container which has a fixed width

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a `min-width` which is large enough to encompass the divs. Also, you had an extra quotation mark in your jsfiddle which was preventing your styling from being applied and for some reason the `height` property was set to `0`. I've adapted your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/HFWnP/) to display the behaviour I think your after.

Comment: Mohamed Meligy's solution is much better.